# How to connect IBM DB2 from Java? Error: .. not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am attempting to connect to an IBM DB2 instance using db2jcc4. 
Below is my configuration and I have had no luck.

POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc4</artifactId>
    <version>10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Bean:

```
@Bean 
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:db2://Host:Port/DatabaseName");
    dataSource.setUsername("Username");
    dataSource.setPassword("Password");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Currently I am running into the following error.

> An attempt was made to access a database, DatabaseName, which was
>   either not found or does not support transactions. ERRORCODE=-4499

Comment: Do you know on which operating-system the Db2-server runs ( i.e Z/OS, i-Series, Linux/Unix/Windows) ?

Comment: If the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, try default port numbers 50000  and 60000 .  When asking for help for Db2 always give the operating-system of the Db2-server, because this determines the answers.

Comment: Where is the DB running? If locally your installer should have told you what port it listening to. If remote, then ask the DBA. DB2 is quite convoluted, and you won't be able to easily guess. Also, are you sure the "DatabaseName" exists and is "active"? I mean, there are so many details. You better ask the DBA.